# Integral with polynomial

Tags: integration, polynomials

I have a problem with this this integral.
$\int \frac x{x^2+2x+2}  \,dx$

I know that result is connected with logarithm, because the numerator is derivative of  denominator, but i can't figure how to solve it. Substitution for $x^2+2x+2$ doesn't work.

Comment: complete the square, and if you dare, the answer will be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic solutions are nice and fun, but we can also approach this in a pedestrian fashion.

A standard way to do this type of problem comes by completing the square in the denominator. In this case we have $x^2+2x+2=(x+1)^2+1$, so we try a substitution of $u=x+1$ giving us

$$\int\frac{x}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx=\int\frac{x}{(x+1)^2+1}\,dx=\int\frac{u-1}{u^2+1}\,du$$

Now we can split this up into two easy integrals:

$$\int\frac{u-1}{u^2+1}\,du=\int\frac{u}{u^2+1}\,du-\int\frac{1}{u^2+1}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(u^2+1\right)-\arctan(u)+C$$

where in the first part we just used the substitution of $u^2+1$ and the second part we recognized as the $\arctan$ function. Plugging back $u=x+1$, we get the solution
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(x^2+2x+2\right)-\arctan(x+1)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try breaking the numerator into $(x^2+2x+2)'=2x+2$ and a constant and trying to complete the square in second term.

> $$\small\int\frac{x{\rm d}x}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac12\int\frac{(2x+2){\rm d}x}{x^2+2x+2}-\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{(x+1)^2+1}=\frac12\ln|x^2+2x+2|-\arctan(x+1)+\text{constant}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can write the integrand as
$$\frac{x}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac12\frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$$